# How to identify the ultimate parent from a nested table structure using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

[image]

My question is: **how do I programmatically identify the ultimate parent?**

Here are the rules explained through an example:

- the id `5.0`'s parent is `51.0`. The id `51.0` has no parent. Therefore, the id `5.0`'s ultimate parent is `51.0`.
- the id `6.0`'s parent is `1.0`. The id `1.0`'s parent is `10.0`. The id `10.0` has no parent. Therefore, the id `6.0`'s ultimate parent is `10.0`.
- the id `2.0` has no parent. Therefore, the ultimate parent_id for `2.0` is `2.0`

There are no duplicates in the *id* field and I don't know beforehand how many levels of nesting there could be in the id structure.

Here is the code for this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': pd.Series([5., 6, 2, 51, 1, 70, 10])
              ,'parent_id': pd.Series([51, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan])})
original_df['ultimate_parent_id'] = ''
original_df
```

Here is what the final table should look like:

[image]

Here is the code for generating that file.

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': pd.Series([5., 6, 2, 51, 1, 70, 10])
              ,'parent_id': pd.Series([51, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan])})
final_df['ultimate_parent_id'] = pd.Series([51., 10, 2, 51, 10, 70, 10])
final_df
```

If possible, I would be very interested both in solutions that use a while loop as well as solutions that utilized vectorized operations.

Comment: This task is inherently sequential (not vectorizable). Pandas is a bad tool for such job. If you know the maximal path-to-parent length N and have enough memory space, you can probably join the dataframe to itself N times.

Comment: @DYZ Pandas is just the format that the data happens to be in to start and end with. **I'd definitely be open to a solution that relies on a different data structure** as long as it could be converted back to into a 2-dimensional table structure afterwards.

Comment: For example:  `original_df.to_dict()` would turn it into a dictionary format. It's fine to make the solution starting point this dictionary: `{'id': {0: 5.0, 1: 6.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 51.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 70.0, 6: 10.0},
 'parent_id': {0: 51.0, 1: 1.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 10.0, 5: nan, 6: nan}}`

Answer (score 2):

In the same vein as @Vaishali's answer, here is a version that uses Python looping over the major operations, but uses `np / pd` operations within the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
        { 'id': pd.Series([5., 6, 2, 51, 1, 70, 10]),
        'parent_id': pd.Series([51, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 51, np.nan])
        }
    )

def find_ultimate_parents(df):
    # Make a copy of df, using 'id' as the index so we can lookup parent ids
    df2 = df.set_index(df['id'])
    df2['nextpar'] = df2['parent_id']

    # Next-parent-2 not null - fake it for now
    np2nn = df2['nextpar'].notnull()

    while np2nn.any():
        # Lookup df2[parent-id], since the index is now by id. Get the
        # parent-id (of the parent-id), put that value in nextpar2.
        # So basically, if row B.nextpar has A, nextpar2 has (parent-of-A), or Nan.

        # Set na_action='ignore' so any Nan doesn't bother looking up, just copies
        # the Nan to the next generation.
        df2['nextpar2'] = df2['nextpar'].map(df2['parent_id'], na_action='ignore')

        # Re-evaluate who is a Nan in the nextpar2 column.
        np2nn = df2['nextpar2'].notnull()

        # Only update nextpar from nextpar2 if nextpar2 is not a Nan. Thus, stop
        # at the root.
        df2.loc[np2nn, 'nextpar'] = df2[np2nn]['nextpar2']

    # At this point, we've run out of parents to look up. df2['nextpar'] has
    # the "ultimate" parents.

    return df2['nextpar']


df['ultimate_parent_id'] = find_ultimate_parents(df)
print(df)
```

The loop guard checks `np2nn.any()` which is a vector op on a boolean Series. Each pass through the loop looks up the "next parent", so the number of passes through the loop will be the maximum depth of any child-parent chain. The worst case in **O(N),** for a list like 1->2->3->4->...->n. The best case is 0, for a list with no parents.

The loop does a `.map` with `na_action='ignore'` to simply propagate Nan values. This is **O(fast-N)** times the cost of the index lookup, which *should* be **O(1).**

With the `nextpar2` field computed, the loop re-computes `np2nn` using a simple `.notnull()` which again is **O(fast-N).**

Finally, the `nextpar` field is updated from `nextpar2,` which again should be **O(fast-N).**

Thus, worst-case performance is **O(slow-N * fast-N),** which is **N²**, but it's a Pandas-N², not a Python-N². Average-case should be **O(slow-m * fast-N)** where *m* is the average-case maximum tree depth, and best case is **O(fast-N)** for 1 fast pass through the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with use of map and combine_first. First create a dictionary from the df values for mapping. Now use map on parent_id to map those values first and then use map again to map values to id. Combine_first will ensure that values mapped from parent_id gets precedence. Final combine_first to fill out NaN values with id.

```
d = final_df.dropna().set_index('id').to_dict()
final_df['ultimate_parent_id'] = 
final_df['parent_id'].map(d['parent_id'])\
.combine_first(final_df['id'].map(d['parent_id']))\
.combine_first(final_df['id'])
```

You get

```
    id      parent_id   ultimate_parent_id
0   5.0     51.0        51.0
1   6.0     1.0         10.0
2   2.0     NaN         2.0
3   51.0    NaN         51.0
4   1.0     10.0        10.0
5   70.0    NaN         70.0
6   10.0    NaN         10.0
```

Comment: @Vaishali, thank you for your answer. DYZ is correct, I'm looking for a solution that works with an arbitrary (previously unknown) tree height.

Comment: @josiah, I see your point. It can be done with a loop but Pandas answers with loops are rarely optimum. May be Pandas is bad tool for this as DYZ mentioned

Comment: @Vaishali I am definitely open to a solution that does not rely on Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first cleanup the DataFrame and get rid of the `nan`s. A negative number is a good replacement:

```
original_df = original_df.fillna(-1).astype(int)
```

Convert the DataFrame into a dictionary:

```
d = original_df.set_index('id').to_dict()['parent_id']
#{1: 10, 2: -1, 51: -1, 5: 51, 6: 1, 10: -1, 70: -1}
```

Now, you need a recursive function to translate an ID into the ultimate parent ID:

```
def translate(x):
    return x if d[x] == -1 else translate(d[x])
```

Apply the recursive function to each dictionary key, collect the results into another DataFrame:

```
ultimate = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series({x: translate(x) for x in d.keys()}), 
                 columns=('ultimate_parent_id', ))
```

Combine the result with the original DataFrame:

```
original_df.merge(ultimate, left_on='id', right_index=True)

#   id  parent_id  ultimate_parent_id
#0   5         51                  51
#1   6          1                  10
#2   2         -1                   2
#3  51         -1                  51
#4   1         10                  10
#5  70         -1                  70
#6  10         -1                  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @adhast's answer, the last line the function(find_ultimate_parents(df)) should be

```
return df2['nextpar'].values
```

df2 is using df['id'] as an index so doesn't correspond to df's index.

Below is the complete script.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    { 'id': pd.Series([5., 6, 2, 51, 1, 70, 10]),
    'parent_id': pd.Series([51, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 51, np.nan])
    }
)

def find_ultimate_parents(df):
    # Make a copy of df, using 'id' as the index so we can lookup parent ids
    df2 = df.set_index(df['id'])
    df2['nextpar'] = df2['parent_id']

    # Next-parent-2 not null - fake it for now
    np2nn = df2['nextpar'].notnull()

    while np2nn.any():
        # Lookup df2[parent-id], since the index is now by id. Get the
        # parent-id (of the parent-id), put that value in nextpar2.
        # So basically, if row B.nextpar has A, nextpar2 has (parent-of-A), or Nan.

        # Set na_action='ignore' so any Nan doesn't bother looking up, just copies
        # the Nan to the next generation.
        df2['nextpar2'] = df2['nextpar'].map(df2['parent_id'], na_action='ignore')

        # Re-evaluate who is a Nan in the nextpar2 column.
        np2nn = df2['nextpar2'].notnull()

        # Only update nextpar from nextpar2 if nextpar2 is not a Nan. Thus, stop
        # at the root.
        df2.loc[np2nn, 'nextpar'] = df2[np2nn]['nextpar2']

    # At this point, we've run out of parents to look up. df2['nextpar'] has
    # the "ultimate" parents.

    return df2['nextpar'].values


df['ultimate_parent_id'] = find_ultimate_parents(df)
print(df)
```