# Identifying ultimate parents in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following dataframe with a column of `Child` and a column of `Parents`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Child': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A1', 'A1', 'A4', 'A2', 'A3'],
               'Parent': ['B1', 'B2', 'A2', 'B3', 'A4', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6']})

df

  Child Parent
0    A1     B1
1    A2     B2
2    A3     A2
3    A1     B3
4    A1     A4
5    A4     B4
6    A2     B5
7    A3     B6
```

There are duplicate `children` and some of them appear in the `parent` column. I would like to know the ultimate parents. This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766413/how-to-identify-the-ultimate-parent-from-a-nested-table-structure-using-python) but with duplicates in the `Child` column. The output I would like is something like the following:

```
  Child                                  Links   Ult_Parents
0    A1       (A1 - B1, A1 - B3, A1 - A4 - B4)  (B1, B3, B4)
1    A2                     (A2 - B2, A2 - B5)      (B2, B5)
2    A3  (A3 - A2 - B2, A3 - A2 - B5, A3 - B6)  (B2, B5, B6)
3    A4                              (A4 - B4)          (B4)
```

A1 has clear parents B1 and B3, but also B4 because it is linked to A4. A2 has simply B2 and B5. I am interested in the links between them but mainly on the ultimate parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
def all_descendants_nx():
    DiG = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'Parent','Child',create_using=nx.DiGraph())
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records([(n1,n2) for n1 in DiG.nodes() for n2 in nx.ancestors(DiG, n1)], columns=['Child','Ult_Parents'])

df = all_descendants_nx()
df = df.loc[df.Ult_Parents.str.startswith("B")]
print(df)

df['Links'] = df.Child.astype('str') + ' - ' + df.Ult_Parents.astype('str')
df = df.groupby('Child').agg(lambda x: sorted(x.tolist())).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I then plot the resulting DiGraph?